# Am using selenium with java for automating web based application. I couldnt interact with browse button

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

when trying to click on browse button, shows webdriver invalid argument exception. The document can be attached only through sendkeys, please help

shows run time exception 
this is my xpath

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@type='file']")
private WebElement eleAttachDoc;
```

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML, code trials, error (if any)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to click and upload file.
A window popup should be displayed when click that cannot be handled by selenium so instead
This element can be handled using SendKeys with argument of you file location (absolute path) which will upload file directly.

Comment: I have used the robot class to attach document from local machine, Now the browse button is not clickable.. I can attach the document only through sendkeys. Is there any way to click on browse button

Answer (score 0):

As per the question, you are trying to upload a file.

In some fields, depending on the  design, you can send the path directly.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("uploadfile_cv")).sendKeys("C:\\mycv.pdf");
```

If the above solution is not working only, you can use Java toolkit to upload a file. Please see the below code. Kindly try this and give feedback.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FileUploadUsingJavaToolKitExample {


   WebDriver driver;


    @Test(priority=1)
    public void navigateToWebSiteAndUploadFile() throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException, InterruptedException, AWTException {

         // Create a file object 
        File f = new File("resources\\DemoUpload.txt");

        // Get the absolute path of file f 
        String absoluteFilePath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        //Copy the file path to clipboard
        StringSelection  autoCopiedFilePath = new StringSelection(absoluteFilePath);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(autoCopiedFilePath, null); 

        //Navigate to the URL
        driver.get("https://codepen.io/rcass/pen/MmYwEp");
        driver.switchTo().frame("result"); //switching the frame by name
        //Click on a button which opens the popup           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fileToUpload']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //This will paste the file path and name in the file explorer by pressing Ctrl +V combination.
        Robot  robot = new Robot(); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);  

        // Pause should be used here to perform the action properly and release the  Ctrl +V keys

        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);  
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        //press enter key after giving the file path.   
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi I have used the code which yu have sent,, but my problem is i couldn't click the choose file